# "A server timeout has occurred" error connecting Dreamweaver to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, wamp, wampserver

I am trying to connect my website to MySQL on localhost under WAMP.

Whenever I enter my details in the MySQL connection tab and click "databases", it crashes and gives me the error:

A server timeout has occurred. Here are the possible reasons.

1. Please make sure that the web server is up and running.
2. Please verify that the ODBC DSN exists on the testing server.

The web server is up and running but I'm not sure how to do the second step. I also changed the ports to 81 so not sure if I messed something up in doing that.

I also know to this and these forums so thanks for your help :)

Comment: Did you change your config file to listen on port 81?  PHP on WAMP usually runs on port 80.

Comment: Yeah I have done that. Maybe I should try a different port?

Comment: I have also tried a fresh install but to no avail.

Comment: Do you mean you changed the MYSQL Listening port to 81 or the Apache Listening port to 81? Or did you change both to 81???

Comment: I think we'd have to see your connection code.

Comment: I changed the Apache Listening port to 81. Do both need to be changed?

Comment: Is the PHP tag relevant? It feels you want to connect your IDE to MySQL, not a PHP script :-?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem!

When I was setting up the database connection, for the MySQL option I was including the apache port.

For anyone else with the same problem, make sure you just have localhost as opposed to localhost:8888

[image: What I'm talking about]

Seems so obvious now.

Comment: Is this part of your PHP application or a dialog from Dreamweaver?